# map words in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I want to map each character of words of english_words library. For that I used charaters.map and that works but I want to make container for the each character. this is my code:

```
   // ignore_for_file: prefer_const_literals_to_create_immutables

import 'package:english_words/english_words.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyApp({ Key? key }) : super(key: key);
  @override
  _MyAppState createState() => _MyAppState();
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  final WordPair words = WordPair.random();
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
       return MaterialApp(
      // ignore: avoid_print
      home: Scaffold(body: Text('${words.first.characters.map((a) => )}''. ',)
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can wrap the text in a `Column`

```dart
Column(
  children: words.first.characters.map((a) => 
    Text(a),
  ).toList(),
)
```

Comment: thanl you very much

Answer (score 0):

`WordPair.random().first` returns a `String`, that can be represented using `ListView`, `Column`...

```dart
class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  final String fWords = WordPair.random().first;
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      // ignore: avoid_print
      home: Scaffold(
          body: ListView.builder(
        itemCount: fWords.length,
        itemBuilder: (context, index) {
          return Container(
            height: 50,
            alignment: Alignment.center,
            child: Text(fWords[index]),
          );
        },
      )),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Sample using;  (Also you can use list view)

```dart
return Column(children: words.first.characters.map((a) => Container(child:Text("$a"))).toList());
```